# Using xpath expression in grails on node objects

Tags: xml, grails, xpath

I wonder if it is possible to use xpath liky syntax on node objects in grails.

```
<root>   
   <enrichedData datatable="ROUTING">
        <customer>234</customer>
   </enrichedData>
   <enrichedData datatable="TABLE2">
        <location>aaa</location>
    </enrichedData>
</root>
```

With this xml structure, it is simple to use this xpath expression:

```
/data/enrichedData[@datatable='ROUTING']/customer
```

When I access this with nodes, I use this code

```
root.data.enrichedData.each {
   if(it.attributes().get("datatable"=="ROUTING")) {
     //do some stuff here 
   }
```

Is there another way to access a node with a specific attribute in grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.find and .findAll work.  I added another ROUTING node to your example for clarity:

```
<root>   
  <enrichedData datatable="ROUTING">
    <customer>234</customer>
  </enrichedData>
  <enrichedData datatable="TABLE2">
    <location>aaa</location>
  </enrichedData>
  <enrichedData datatable="ROUTING">
    <customer>567</customer>
  </enrichedData>
</root>
```

But this is of course not necessary.

I can then find ROUTING nodes, and operate on their customers, as such:

`data.enrichedData.findAll{it.@datatable == "ROUTING"}.customer.each { println it.text() }`

It's possible to add additional .finds farther down the chain, but that should give you the general idea.